# Plotly: Unreadable text in hover info

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

With Plotly I can generate a barplot with this code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace0 = dict(
    x=list(range(24)),
    y=[163, 154, 114, 61, 32, 19, 20, 20, 26, 38, 67, 102, 132, 159],
    name="Two",
    type="bar",
    marker={"color": "rgba(81, 133, 198, 0.3)", "line": {"width": 0}},
)
trace1 = dict(
    x=list(range(24)),
    y=[0, 0, 0, 4, 19, 37, 49, 49, 39, 25, 7, 1, 0, 0],
    name="One",
    type="bar",
    marker={"color": "rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0)", "line": {"width": 0}},
)
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    hovermode="x",
)
go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout).update_layout(barmode="stack")
```

The only problem is that the label text in the hover info is unreadable, because the background color used is too close to the labels color:

[image]

How can I fix that? Is is possible to change the color of the hover info label text background or the color of the hover info label text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [plotly community forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/change-hover-text-color/28039/3) you can see that:

> The text associated to each hoverbox is in fact the trace name. By
> default, the line_color/marker_color is inherited by the trace name
> color to help users identify each scatter trace by color. You can
> change only bgcolor and font_color

So no, there does not seem to be a way you can change what you want here without also changing the color properties of the traces. If you *really* want to keep the colors and overcome the poor visibility of the info in the hoverboxes, you can change your `hovermode="x"` to `hovermode="x unified"` and get this instead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I posted another alternative. As you have mentioned, it is not possible to change that style just yet (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2342), but it is possible to remove it. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to remove the extra text using `hovertemplate`. You can use `<extra></extra>` in the template in order to have it removed.

That also gives extra flexibility to control how the hover info looks like.

In example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace0 = dict(
    x=list(range(24)),
    y=[163, 154, 114, 61, 32, 19, 20, 20, 26, 38, 67, 102, 132, 159],
    name="Two",
    type="bar",
    marker={"color": "rgba(81, 133, 198, 0.3)", "line": {"width": 0}},
    hovertemplate="<b>Two</b><br>%{y:,.2f} €<extra></extra>",
)
trace1 = dict(
    x=list(range(24)),
    y=[0, 0, 0, 4, 19, 37, 49, 49, 39, 25, 7, 1, 0, 0],
    name="One",
    type="bar",
    marker={"color": "rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0)", "line": {"width": 0}},
    hovertemplate="<b>One</b><br>%{y:,.2f} €<extra></extra>",
)
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    hovermode="x",
)
go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout).update_layout(barmode="stack")
```

[image]